# R: lts regression: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, robust, lts

I'm trying to do a variable selection using LTS regression but I encounter with this error.

```
sigma.full<-summary(ltsreg(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5))$scale
```

> Error in summary(ltsreg(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5))$scale: $ operator is
>   invalid for atomic vectors

Can someone help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Look at `str(summary(ltsreg(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5)))`.

Comment: reproducible example please?  What package are you using (and what version)? Why do you think that the result of `summary(ltsreg(...))` is a list with a `scale` element?

Comment: What package are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the function `MASS::ltsreg`

Use

```
sigma.full<-ltsreg(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5)$scale
```

Have a look at `?ltsreg`.

The result of `ltsreg(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5)` itself has the scale-information.
The summary of it does not have a `$scale` element.

Have a look at `str(summary(ltsreg(...)))` as Roland suggests